# Can I Register for Push Notifications Outside of AppDelegate.m?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

My app is able to successfully register for push notifications but I would like to move the pop-up alert to a different area of the app

If I implement the same code from `AppDelegate.m` to a different screen, `Other.m`, of my app, it never registers:

```
-(void)buttonTapped {
    // Register for Push Notifications
    UIRemoteNotificationType notifyTypes = (UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |                     UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge);

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:notifyTypes];
}


#pragma mark - APNS Functions
-(void)application:application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken {
    NSLog(@"didRegisterForRemoteNotifications - 1");
}


-(void)application:application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:error {
    NSLog(@"didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotifications");
}
```

If I enable `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` in my `AppDelegate.m`, the `AppDelegate.m` instance of the method gets called from my `Other.m`, but that is not how I want this to work.

Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, of course.

You can register wherever you want with using

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

but didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken is only available in AppDelegate

Comment: is there a way for Other.m to know if the registration is successful or fails?

Comment: You can use NSNotificationCenter to trigger remotenotification register succesful or fail in any ViewController

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)application:application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken
```

This is the protocol method of the UIApplicationDelegate protocol, so it will be triggered on [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate. This is the AppDelegate by default.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer was deprecated in iOS 8.0. Following Swift code works for iOS 9.0:

```
let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Badge, .Sound, .Alert], categories: nil)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
```